# Availability of mean squared slope or wave spectra data for the sea surface

Tags: ocean, waves, open-data

The mean squared slope is a property of the sea surface that is often sensed by microwave radars [[1]](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/97JC02443/abstract;jsessionid=33BD51CD5995EF23CE34FCF0FAC31CBB.f01t01) [[2]](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/1520-0426%282000%29017%3C1092%3ATMSSOO%3E2.0.CO%3B2).

While spatial data for sea surface salinity, sea surface height, and significant wave height exist (Ex. [[3]](http://www.aviso.altimetry.fr/en/home.html) [[4]](http://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/aquarius)), I've not been able to find spatial mean squared slope data, or wave spectrum data (from which mean squared slope can be derived). The only data I know of are from the [National Buoy Data Center](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov), but they are point measurements only.

I'm currently working on a microwave remote sensing project, and spatial mean squared slope data would prove to be helpful. Does anyone know if spatial mean squared slope or wave spectrum data exist anywhere?

Comment: I can't help directly, but you may get better answers if you specify whether there's a particular part of the world that you're interested in (possibly US waters, since you link to NOAA?) or whether anywhere will do.

Comment: Anywhere will do just fine. We could run a wave model with surface wind inputs, and get the MSS that way, but its accuracy would depend on the wave model itself.